# How to concatenate multiple node values from XML stored in image field - with a twist

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath

I have XML which is stored in an image field in SQL.
I can extract the xml with a CAST, and then xpath to the node I want.
The issue is the node is repeatable and I don't know how many of them there will be, so I have to concatenate the values as well.  And just as final addition I also need to split replace certain characters in each...

So I can get close to what I want to do with this:

```
SELECT c.ID, REPLACE((CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), ISNULL(zd.ValidContent, x.Content))) AS XML).value('(//preamble, //preamblehang)[1]', N'nvarchar(max)')), ' – ','|') FROM docs c INNER JOIN zones zd on c.docid = zd.docid ...
```

*(This is actually in view with lots of other entities and case statement, but I stripped it for the sake of simplicity)*

This will result in:
[Keyword result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwiFV.jpg)

But the XML that I get from the CAST actually looks like this:

```
....
<Arule>&#160;</Arule>
<preamble>[1]&#160;&#160;Merger &#8211; Large merger &#8211; Approval of merger &#8211; Subject to employment conditions.</preamble>
<preamble>[2]&#160;&#160;Merger &#8211; Large merger &#8211; Effect on competition &#8211; Lessening or preventing competition.</preamble>
<preamble>[3]&#160;&#160;Merger &#8211; Large merger &#8211; Efficiency defence &#8211; Section 12A &#8211; Pro-competitive gains outweighing loss to local consumers and production.</preamble>
<preamble>[4]&#160;&#160;Merger &#8211; Large merger &#8211; Public interest &#8211; Merger effects on employment.</preamble>
<preamble>[5]&#160;&#160;Merger &#8211; Large merger &#8211; Relevant product and geographic markets defined on a broad and narrow basis.</preamble>
<preamble>[6]&#160;&#160;Merger &#8211; Large merger &#8211; Market shares and concentration.</preamble>
<EdSummary>Editor&#8217;s Summary</EdSummary>
...
```

There are multiple 'preamble' nodes and my select only returns the first one and then does the Replace on the string.  I need to get the string for all the nodes and then do the string replacement. Or Replace and then Concat.

I assume that I need to insert a query() statement somewhere with a For statement inside, but nothing has worked so far.  Any help would be great.

Note: the `&#8211;` in the XML is the emdash (–) character that I replace with pipe.  The nodes will also then need to be seperated by the pipe character.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Why are you storing xml in the image datatype? Not only is there an xml datatype but the image datatype has been deprecated for almost 15 years now. Above that I don't understand the question here. This would be a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Hi. Which SQL Server version do you use?

Comment: @SeanLange Good question. This setup is legacy from a bespoke solution that was developed for us a good couple of years ago. We are looking at recreating it, but it is a very large part of our current content management system and business critical.

Comment: @wp78de.  This is on MS SQL Server 2016 SE.

Comment: You still haven't provided enough detail for anybody to help or understand what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry guys, I managed to get something going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around a bit I managed to get what I am looking for.  I will now see to maybe adapt this to get it into a function or maybe in a stored procedure to pre-build a table I can use to join on in the view.

Here's the SQL statement that gets me the result I want:

```
Declare @xml xml, @ItemID int

Select @xml = CAST('<xml>' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), z.ValidContent)) + '</xml>' AS XML)
FROM docs c WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN zone z ON c.ID = z.ID
WHERE c.ItemID = @ItemID

CREATE TABLE #KeywordData (nodes nvarchar(max))

INSERT INTO #KeywordData
select replace (B.x.value('.', N'nvarchar(max)'), ' – ','|')
from @xml.nodes('/xml') as A(x)
outer apply A.x.nodes('./preamble') as B(x)

SELECT SUBSTRING(
(
    SELECT '|' + nodes as 'data()'
    FROM #KeywordData FOR XML PATH('')
), 2, 9999) as keywords

DROP TABLE #KeywordData
```